# Setting up AD Groups in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory

I'm trying to set add Active directory groups, to various different groups on an Ubuntu (11.10) box.

I've managed to get it to accept Active Directory users, but when I try adding AD Groups to etc\groups\ there is no joy..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Groups in *nix (that includes Ubuntu) cannot contain other groups.

AD groups are available as regular groups if you have AD membership configured correctly, try

```
getent group
```

and see if the groups are listed, if yes, then you can use them directly:

```
chgrp ad-group-A /some/dir
```

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [PowerBroker Identity Services](http://www.beyondtrust.com/products/powerbroker-identity-services-open-edition/) (formerly Likewise Open). There's an Open edition and an Enterprise edition, they allow much more fine-grained mapping of AD groups then is possible just using Winbind for AD membership. The Enterprise edition gives you complete control over group policy. But the Open edition covers 99% of the cases I require on a day to day basis. I highly recommend looking at the documentation for PowerBroker to see if it will be a good fit for your use case.